# How can I fix this function?

Tags: python

The value of hamburger at the bottom won't multiply times the value menu is inputted. The count gives me two answers only and they arent correct to the actual amount of times (menu) inputs.

```
def input1():
  menu = input("""
  hamburger--:  """)
  loop = input("Would you like to add another Food: (y/n)?")
  return menu, loop

def calc(menu, loop):
  hamburger = 1.25
  count = 1
  if menu == "h":
    print(loop)
  if loop == "y":
    menu, loop =input1()
    calc(menu, loop)

  if loop == "n":
    menu = (count)

    menu = int(count)
    print(menu * 1.25)
    count+=1

def main():
  menu, loop =input1()
  calc(menu, loop)
```

Comment: `count` is already an integer then why are you again doing `menu = int(count)`?

Comment: i can fix that the issue is with the multiplication.

Comment: Looks like you want `count` to persist through the recursion.

Comment: I want count to keep the value of inputs the user types in the variable (menu), then multiply that by the variable (hamburger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recursive call, you want to add each value

```
<current value> + calc() + calc()....
```

Like this:

```
def input1():
    menu = input("""
    hamburger--:  """)
    loop = input("Would you like to add another Food: (y/n)?")
    return menu, loop

def calc():
    # Get current value
    menu, loop = input1()
    cost = 0
    if 'h' == menu:
        cost = 1.25
    # Example other items
    elif 'f' == menu:   # Fries
        cost = .75
    # Make recursive calls, if needed
    if loop == "y":
        cost += calc()
    # Return the total (so far)
    return cost

def main():
    print(calc())
```

Or you can put all the menu items in a dictionary:

```
full_menu = {'h': 1.25, 'f': .75, 's': 1.0}

def calc():
    menu, loop = input1()
    cost = 0
    if menu in full_menu:
        cost = full_menu[menu]
    if loop == "y":
        cost += calc()
    return cost
```

Comment: it won't return the int(menu) it gives the invalid literal for base 10

Comment: @DesertFoxAirsoft0000 What are you entering? I assumed `menu` was the number of burgers.

Comment: menu would be a letter like "h" for hamburger. depending on how many times that letter was entered, once done the program would calculate the amount of times entered by the value of cost = 1.25

Comment: @DesertFoxAirsoft0000 Ok. Updated answer.

Comment: the point is that if the letter begins with "H" than every time you say you want "H" it will count up all of them and multiply it times 1.25

Comment: So user can enter "hhhhh" for 5 hamburgers? Or "hhffsss" for 2 burgers, 2 fries, and 3 sodas?

Answer (score 0):

I think (if i understood the problem correctly) that the problem is you only do the "count += 1" the last iteration. 
Imagine that you do this 2 times

because the if loop == "n" only happens when you don't want to add item.

Here is a suggestion of what i think coulf be better solution:

```
PRICES = {
   'hamburger': 1.25
}

def get_input():
    menu_item = input('Item')
    loop = input("Would you like to add another Food: (y/n)?")
    return menu_item, loop

def calc():
  # Start a item count  
  item_count = {
      'hamburguer': 0
  }
  finished = False
  while not finished:
      menu_item, loop = get_input()
      # Check if item in menu
      if menu_item in PRICES.keys():
          item_count[menu_item] += 1
      else:
          print('Sorry, the item is not in the menue')
      # Check if no more items are expected  
      if loop == "n"
        finished = True

  return sum([ PRICES[item] * ammount (item, ammount) in item_count.values()])

def main():
  pritn(calc())
```

It's considered a bad practice to define constants (like the hamburger price) in the function. 
Also, it can be confusing to override the parameters (like menu).

It is likely that I haven't understood the question correctly. But I hope this helps you. 
Don't hesitate to correct me and sorry for the bad English